# Calculating standard deviation in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write an equation to find the standard deviation of a list of integers in Haskell and after wracking my brain for an hour, I think I've figured out how to write the equation. It's giving me errors though and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
listLength :: (Num a) => [a] -> a
listLength [] = 0
listLength (x:xs) = 1 + listLength xs

listMeanInt x = listSum x `div` listLength x

listStdDev x = sqrt(numerator x `div` denominator x)
denominator x = (listLength x) - 1
numerator (x:xs) = if (x /= []) then ((x - listMeanInt x)^2) + (numerator xs) else 0
```

The functions listLength and listMeanInt are used in other parts of my program so I'm confident they are not the problem. When I try to load the module, I get errors for listStdDev and numerator.

For the former, I'm given the error

```
Non type-variable argument in the constraint: Integral [a]
When checking the inferred type
    listStdDev :: forall a. (Integral [a], Floating [a]) => [[a]] -> [a].
```

I'm not sure what that's saying? Maybe that the denominator is expected to be a float even though I'm using div? I'm confused by this and would like some clarification before I set something on fire.

As for the latter, I get told

```
Occurs check: cannot construct the infinite type: a ~ [a]
In the second argument of ‘(-)’, namely ‘listMeanInt x’,
In the first argument of ‘(^)’, namely ‘(x - listMeanInt x)’,
In the first argument of ‘(+)’, namely ‘((x - listMeanInt x) ^ 2)’.
Relevant bindings include xs :: [[a]], x :: [a], numerator :: [[a]] -> [a].
```

I am completely lost for words as to how to interpret this; I'm very new to Haskell. Could I please have some help understanding what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: The code is wrong in a few places, and the type inference consequently is trying to assign the wrong types. Try to add a type annotation for _all_ your functions, and the type errors will become clearer. Right now, `numerator` must be a function taking a list-of-lists, which is wrong, for instance.

Comment: How is `listSum` defined?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you may calculate the standard deviation as follows;

```
stdev :: [Float] -> Float
stdev xs = sqrt . average . map ((^2) . (-) axs) $ xs
           where average = (/) <$> sum <*> realToFrac . length
                 axs     = average xs
```

It's best to define our list as a `Float` type. This saves us from some conversions.

The `average` function; `(/) <$> sum <*> realToFrac . length` is in fact an `Applicative` approach in which we feed the `(/)` function's two parameters with the results of `sum` and `realToFrac . length` from a common parameter; a list. So it will be like;

`sum ([1,2,3] :: [Float]) / (realToFrac . length $ [1,2,3])`

and `map`s first parameter `((^2) . (-) axs)` is a function which will take each element one by one, find it's difference with the list's average and square it. Well... then we calculate the average of them and take square root of it. Accordingly;

```
*Main> stdev [600, 470, 170, 430, 300]
147.32277
```